# Tensorflow Data cardinality is ambigous with multiple inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a model with two inputs for text classification with additional input 'subject' of text. One of my inputs is for text - it gets vectorized by a vectorization layer. The other is 'subject' as int. These are concatenated later. In my code below, `x_train_text` is simply a list of texts. `x_train_subject` is a list of integers. These two and `y_train_int` has same sizes. However, even though the sizes are the same(4499), I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 2
  y sizes: 4499
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

CODE:

```
MAX_TOKENS_NUM = 5000  # Maximum vocab size.
MAX_SEQUENCE_LEN = 40  # Sequence length to pad the outputs to.
EMBEDDING_DIMS = 100

text_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
subject_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int32)

text_layer = vectorize_layer(text_input)
text_layer = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(MAX_TOKENS_NUM + 1, EMBEDDING_DIMS)(text_layer)
text_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(text_layer)

subject_layer = tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding(
    num_tokens=len(subjects), output_mode='one_hot', sparse=False
)(subject_input)

concatenated = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([text_layer, subject_layer])

output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(labels))(concatenated)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[text_input, subject_input], outputs=output)

model.summary()
model.compile(loss=losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy())
```

FIT FUNCTION :

```
epochs = 100
history = model.fit(
    [x_train_text,x_train_subject],
    y=y_train_int,
    epochs=epochs)
```

What could be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the fit function to receive inputs as Pandas.DataFrame.values as below it works.

FIT FUNCTION :

```
epochs = 100
history = model.fit(
    [pd.DataFrame(x_train_text).values,pd.DataFrame(x_train_subject).values],
    y=pd.DataFrame(y_train_int).values,
    epochs=epochs)
```